# Akka-Http: accept application/json in POST requests

Tags: akka, akka-http

I'm trying to use [circe](https://github.com/travisbrown/circe) to do my JSON (de)serialization in an Akka-Http app, rather than spray-json. For that reason, I want to use the [`entity`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/marshalling-directives/entity.html#entity) directive with `as[String]` to get the string representation of the request body, and then do my own deserialization. But it seems that `entity` is too smart for its own good, and is rejecting anything that does not have the Content-Type `text/plain`.

My understanding from the docs is that implicit magic should let me be able to do something like:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentTypes
entity(as[String].forContentTypes(ContentTypes.`application/json`))
```

But the compiler is not doing the whole thing of inferring that I want `as` to resolve to a `FromEntityUnmarshaller[String]`, which has that implicit method `forContentTypes`, whose result should be converted to a `FromMessageUnmarshaller[String]`, which (due to contravariance) should satisfy the need for a `FromRequestUnmarshaller[String]`.

However, even holding the compilers hand by doing:

```
val jsonRequestToStringUnmarshaller: FromRequestUnmarshaller[String] = 
  messageUnmarshallerFromEntityUnmarshaller(implicitly[FromEntityUnmarshaller[String]].forContentTypes(ContentTypes.`application/json`))
entity(jsonRequestToStringUnmarshaller)
```

my server is *still* rejecting `application/json` requests.

What gives?

**Update**

I can see now that I misunderstood [`forContentTypes`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.1/#akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller), and that it will only narrow, not expand, the Content-Type range that an Unmarshaller will accept. That just explains why my solution isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to give Akka-Http direct marshallers-unmarshallers from / to desired types using circe under the hood.

It may look like: https://github.com/PDXostc/rvi_sota_server/blob/master/common/src/main/scala/org/genivi/sota/marshalling/CirceMarshallingSupport.scala